# Comic about an alien who crashes in a junkyard

Tags: story-identification, comics

An alien who has stolen something valuable from a creepy black and white lady (also an alien) crashes on Earth. He has a pet that looks like a black and white fox-like creature with no mouth. The alien looks like a young boy. A young girl finds him and let's him live with her.

At one point he shrinks a Brontosaurus skeleton at a museum to give to her, but I think she chastises him for doing so. She somehow manages to help him leave Earth to escape black humanoid aliens with pincers for hands who are sent by the creepy alien lady.

I think I read this around 1997-9. It was in English. It was a book, but I can't remember if it was hardback or not. I don't think it was in a series. It was in colour and the style was... unique? I honestly can't remember reading anything else that looked like it.

My mother seems to think it was called something like Jojo/Joejoe from Outer Space. But I don't know if she is right.

Comment: Can you add a little more info? Did you read it in English or another language? Online, as comic books, or a trade paperback collection? Was it color or b&w? Manga-style, eurocomics-style or US style?

Answer (score 10):

### I found it!

Grahame Baker-Smith, *Jo-Jo's Journey* (Bodley Head, 1994).

[WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/31737872)'s description:

> Forced to crash land his space ship on Earth, Jo-Jo the interplanetary collector gets into one scrape after another with his new friend Daisy.

There are a few copies floating around the web (AbeBooks, Amazon, Ebay). The blurb reads:

> Interplanetary collector, Jo-Jo, is being pursued by the dark ships of an enemy planet. Forced to crash land, he heads for the nearest habitable planet — the Blue Planet — known to its residents as … Earth! From here in it's non-stop adventure for Jo-Jo and his new-found earth companion, Daisy. Jo-Jo's troublesome pet, Meep, is never far from his side as the three friends get in and out of one scrape after another. But when Jo-Jo decides to add a dinosaur skeleton to his collection, Daisy knows that this space boy needs to be taught a lesson …

> This stunning graphic novel has an action-packed storyline and exquisite illustrations. Space Boy, Jo-Jo, and punchy heroine, Daisy, are ideal characters to entice children into the world of children's books.

---

### My original post:

I'm almost certain I read the same book in the late-'90s or early 2000s. Unfortunately I don't have it anymore (it was probably donated to somewhere) and haven't been able to find much information online. The name of the alien boy was definitely Jojo (or Jo Jo/Joejoe/Joe Joe, et cetera).

Everything mentioned I recall being in the book. There are a couple of other things that I remember. The alien boy had blonde hair that curled under his eyes and formed points. When his pet, the fox-like thing, drank the milk the young girl put out for her cat, the creature turned a different colour. The girl and her mother lived in a tower block/apartment building that may have been in New York. There was also a feast where the creepy alien lady ate space bugs.

I read it in English too and it was a paperback. Colour. Somewhat unique style, and relatively lifelike. It seemed to be a standalone story.

Comment: That's a nice answer, especially for someone new to the site. I'd like to give you a bounty to kickstart you on the site. I don't think I can actually award it until tomorrow, but be aware that it is coming.